# How can i query for specific matching substrings while ignoring the rest in a SCAN query?

Tags: redis, glob

trying to do a redis `SCAN` command and trying to figure out how to do glob-pattern substring matching for words instead of single characters (using ruby redis gem)

```rb
redis.set("first:url:123", "val1")
redis.set("second:url:123", "val2")
redis.set("third:url:123", "val3")
redis.set("fourth:url:123", "val4")

cursor = 0

pattern = "[first,second]:url:*" ## I only want the first and second keys

redis.scan(cursor, match: pattern)

# => ...
```

--

according to the docs [here](https://redis.io/commands/keys) i found these available options but it looks like it only works for single characters, how can i use it for words?

> h[ae]llo matches hello and hallo, but not hillo

Edit:

https://globster.xyz/

makes me think that using `{first,second}:url:123` should work, but that doesnt seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

Redis doesn't support regex expressions for key name patterns, only glob-like expressions.
You can revert to an [`EVAL` Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval) if you are amendment about it. Here's one that does it, but do read the comments: https://gist.github.com/itamarhaber/19c8393f465b62c9cfa8